# How to Share Builtin Mac Bluetooth with Windows 7 VM through Parallels 8

Tags: windows-7, mac, bluetooth, parallels

There seems to be a lot of noise on how to do this.

This tutorial should be all that there is: http://kb.parallels.com/en/114686
But when I go into device manager on Windows, the driver cannot be found for 'Bluetooth USB Host Controller'

This tutorial is great but has broken links and is old now: http://www.mattiouz.com/blog/2007/04/13/how-to-use-the-built-in-mac-bluetooth-in-windows-under-parallels

Is there anyone who has done this successfully?  I really, really need this.

--
MacBook Pro, mid 2012, i5
Windows 7 64bt professional VM
Prallels 8

Comment: I'd post more descriptive images, but I've just started and I don't have a high enough reputation yet.